# Angular cli + protractor + cucumber - selenium

Tags: protractor, cucumber, angular-cli, e2e-testing

I'm wondering if it is possible to run a setup of angular cli project with cucumber e2e tests, using protractor steps, without using a selenium server. When I search for such configurations, I only find ones that have a seleniumAddress setup.

So, is it possible to run it without it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Requires a server running W3C WebDriver specifications

From your question, can you run Protractor without a selenium server? Yes, if you are using a browser driver that follows the [W3C WebDriver](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/) specification. So setting `directConnect: true` (angular-cli default) in your configuration file basically tells Protractor to launch the driver binary, then Protractor creates a driver provider to talk to that binary.

## Driver provider options

The driver providers can be different. Your question also referred to the `seleniumAddress`. So how does this work? Basically, Protractor reads your configuration file and [decides which driver provider to launch](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/driverProviders/index.ts). If you are not using `directConnect` and have decided to use the `seleniumAddress` option in your configuration then you could be either launching an attached session or a hosted driver. Attaching a session means that you have a previous session running and Protractor will launch tests against the session id. Hosted means that you have started your test against a running selenium standalone server. Usually the selenium standalone server is `http://localhost:4444`.

There are other types of driver providers to help launch your tests and if you follow the conditional in `buildDriverProvider` method, you can pick and chose which one you want to launch. Obviously (from the conditional), if you have `directConnect` and `seleniumAddress`, you will launch with a direct connect driver provider.

## A quick note on webdriver-manager

Also a quick note on webdriver-manager. If you plan to launch your Protractor tests on Firefox, you'll need to download Gecko driver. If you use the `seleniumAddress` option, you'll also need to download the selenium-standalone server. The angular-cli only downloads chromedriver with the command, `webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false`. To download the rest, simply remove the flags that are set to false: `webdriver-manager update`

## Cucumber in your configuration

So finally you want cucumber with Protractor. Protractor supports cucumber as a custom framework. You'll need to require the `protractor-cucumber-framework`. Hopefully you have found this on the [configuration in the Protractor-cookbook](https://github.com/angular/protractor-cookbook/blob/master/protractor-typescript-cucumber/config/config.ts).

You should add the following to your configuration to get cucumber working:

```
framework: 'custom',
frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
cucumberOpts: {
  compiler: "ts:ts-node/register",
  monochrome: true,
  strict: true,
  plugin: ["pretty"],
  require: ['../../stepdefinitions/*.ts', '../../support/*.ts'],
  //tags help us execute specific scenarios of feature files
  tags: '@AddScenario,@SubtractScenario,@MultiplyScenario,@DivideScenario,@ModulusScenario'
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Still working on it, but it looks promissing.

Answer (score 1):

You can run protractor tests without selenium server by using `directConnect: true` in your [protractor config](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts). But note this option only currently works with Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Thanks. Angular cli setts the directConnect to true by default. What I want is to find out if anyone has a setup with cucumber tests running with angular cli (without selenium) that could guide me (or maybe I could take a look at the configuration) to understand how to set it up.

Comment: After reading the question several times, this is the answer. If this is not the answer, then the question should be revised.